# Remote Desktop protocol error code 0x112f when using multiple monitors

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

The past years I've had frequent issues with Remote Desktop not being able to connect, with "**protocol error code 0x112f**" (server/client both Windows 10). It doesn't always happen. Sometimes it will work if I try again a few times. It always works if I disable "Use all monitors".

Googling this error just gives me the same "solutions":

1. *"It's caused by insufficient memory"* **(I had 4,7GB available RAM last time it happened)**
2. *"You need to "disable use all monitors"* **(This is a workaround, not a solution!)**
3. *There's a mismatch of monitor resolutions etc.* **(If that was the problem, it would always fail, not only sometimes)**

Does anyone have any idea what other things can cause this issue? I've used multiple monitors previously many years ago, with zero issues, it's only the past 2 years this has started becoming a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Some more workarounds from the post
[protocol error code 0x112f on local machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/292214/protocol-error-code-0x112f-on-local-machine-solved.html).

**Method 1**

> 1. Open gpedit.msc
> 2. Go to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host
>    -> Remote Session Environment
> 3. Change the policy "Use WDDM graphics display driver for Remote Desktop Connections" to enabled.
> 4. Change the policy "Limit number of monitors" to however many monitors you plan to use. I am currently only using 2.
>
> Reboot if necessary.

**Methods 2 and 3**

> This happens when our users are connecting from a home setup with more than 2x screens, the work around is to modify the original RDP settings to be 16-bit color or un-tick the checkbox "use all my monitors" then once in minimize that RDP session and start a new RDP session with the tickbox checked, from what I have seen this is an issue at the source PC end rather than the destination PC.

Comment: Holy moly. I've been running into this issue for YEARS now. The trick with connecting a single monitor first, then (re)connect with all monitors works for me. FINALLY!